# IAM Policy Not launching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have attached the below custom IAM as an inline policy to an IAM user, but when I try to launch EC2 instance through the user login it's not working.My requirement is to allow the user to only launch t2.micro Instance.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1: xxxxxxxxx:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1: xxxxxxxxx:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1: xxxxxxxxx:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1: xxxxxxxxx:subnet/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1: xxxxxxxxx:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any guesses on what might be the Issue?

Comment: "but when I try to launch EC2 instance through the user login it's not working." - what error are you getting?

Comment: launch failed : You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Comment: What is the type of the instance you try to launch?

Comment: "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"

Comment: I think it's difficult without verifying the launch configuration you are using e.g. are you trying to attach IAM role/tagging the instance/volume? A good place to start troubleshoot will be decoding the error message. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your policy lacks the following:

```
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-*"
```

Alternatively, you can define a specific image:

```
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-xxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than limiting the ALLOW, you could permit `ec2:*` but add this policy that **denies** anything other than t2.micro:

```
{
  "Action": [
    "ec2:RunInstances"
  ],
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
      "ec2:InstanceType": [
        "t2.micro"
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

However, be careful because somebody could launch a t2.micro, stop it, modify the instance type, then start it again!

To prevent this, you could add:

```
{
  "Action": [
    "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute"
  ],
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Resource": "*"
},
```